# Getting Data from java Applet using PHP Zend Framework Webservice

Tags: java, php, web-services, zend-framework, applet

I have to make a web-service in Zend Framework for getting data from java applet.

Basically its a game built using Java Applet. I want to store result in my website's mysql database.

So I am trying to make a web service using `Zend_Rest_server`  which will be accessed by Java applet code and I will get result data through web-service and will store them in MySql database.

Let me know if my concept is wrong.  OR if I can do same task in another easier way.

I gone through some online tutorial for `Zend_Rest_Sever` but all are basic.

I made simple server for getting a variable value. But its not working in java application saying "Path not fond" Might be due to zend framework routing url.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*Path not fond"*  Is path disinclined, or DYM 'found'?  ;) By the way.  What path did you specify?

Comment: path of my web-service like : www.example.com/service/index/name/test

Comment: Is the applet also hosted at www.example.com?

Comment: OK ..what do you get if you put www.example.com/service/index/name/test in the address bar of your default browser and surf there directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the Zend_Rest_Route(s) needed?

You might want to check this out: http://mwop.net/blog/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework

Comment: Already gone through this. It's working ok in PHP But not In java